# How to differentiate between differrent hyperlinks in same page in servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets, hyperlink

I have just started learning servlets and I was trying to do a shopping project. 
The problem is that how do i identify that which hyperlink out of several was clicked when all hyperlinks have same action servlet?
here's the code:

HTML code:

```
Product 1 
<a name="sub" value="1" href="Cart">Add to cart?</a>
Product 2
<a name="sub" value="2" href="Cart">Add to cart?</a>
```

Servlet code(Cart.java):

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("...","...","...");
 int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sub").trim());
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select price,qty from product where pid=?");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

}
```

I can't create separate servlet for each hyperlink as there are many hyperlinks on a page and I have multiple pages also. So that's not possible.

I tried adding a value field in the  tag and getting the value using getParameter() but I get a NULL Pointer Exception.
What should I do?
The code runs fine if i explicity set the value for id in the servlet. but that couldn't be done since the servlet will then work for that specific product only.
I am just a beginner an don't know if any method exists in java for this. :(

I also wanted to ask that if several html pages are calling same servlet ,is there any way to get the name of that html file in the servlet?

Comment: If you have a separate question, you should ask it separately.

Comment: not allowed to ask more than 1 ques in 90 minutes :( and by the both questions are related to same code :) –  @Whymarrh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is no way to differentiate between two links to the same resource: the `Cart` resource is the `Cart` resource regardless of who is linking to it.

#### How can you add multiple things to the cart?

You *could* create a new servlet to handle adding each product to the cart:

```
Product 1 <a href="AddProduct1">Add to cart?</a>
Product 2 <a href="AddProduct2">Add to cart?</a>
Product 3 <a href="AddProduct3">Add to cart?</a>
Product 4 <a href="AddProduct4">Add to cart?</a>
<!-- etc. -->
```

But as you noted in your OP, that would not be a great approach — This wouldn't scale.

As with everything, there are many ways to solve this problem. One way would you be to add a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to the resource. Doing so would allow you to pass some data to the servlet (and get that in your servlet via `getParameter("product")`). For example, you can create links like so:

```
Product 1 <a href="Cart?product=1">Add to cart?</a>
Product 2 <a href="Cart?product=2">Add to cart?</a>
```

The above would all link to the same servlet, the same resource, but each link would pass different data to the servlet. Inside your servlet you can get this data and use it to determine what needs to be done:

```
String productId = request.getParameter("product");
// Add product to cart
```

From the Java Javadoc for [`getParameter(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), emphasis mine:

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. **For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.**

[Aside: the `<a>` tag doesn't allow a "value" attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: On anything in particular?

Comment: that query parameter thing. never heard of it.. :(

Comment: yeah i know that a value attribute is not allowed coz eclipse was showing a warning but i did it coz I couldn't think of anything else..